# ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests' for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Have installed pip3 via sudo apt-get. But while trying to check the pip3 --version, its throwing

> ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'

How do i fix this?

server -- Linux Debian 4.9.65-3,
Python version -- Python 3.5.3

p.s. have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip3 but no luck.

Full stack trace:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in
>   
>       from pip import main   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>       from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2345

Comment: The last comment to that issue suggests this could be caused by using `sudo` in front of `pip3`. Which is slightly odd, and shouldn't really be the case.

Comment: have checked the same(github)..but didn't work for me. I am working in prod env and do not have root access.. hence have to use sudo

Comment: Try the following: 1/ uninstall `pip3`, 2/ Verify there is a valid Python 3 on your system (`python3 --version`; let us know which version), 3/ Try using `python3 -m pip --version`, 3b/ try the same again with `sudo` prepended, 4/ Use pip as runnable module: (`sudo`) `python3 -m pip <whatever command>`.

Comment: Could you also update your question with information about your platform (version, variant) and Python 3 version?

Comment: As to having to use sudo: do you need to install packages for the system/other users, or just for yourself?

Comment: just for myself. I need to use sudo as i do not have root permissions.

Comment: If just for yourself, you *don't* need `sudo`: `pip` has a `--user` option, which installs packages locally (user-only) in such a way that Python will find them automatically (on Linux, probably under `$HOME/.local`). Thus, you can try and use `pip3 install <package> --user` to do that.

Comment: NB: Python 3.5.3 is getting old, so support for and compatibility with up-to-date versions of `pip` may be limited.

Comment: issue is still there even without sudo.

Comment: But can you run it as `python3 -m pip --version`?

Comment: this too gives the same error

Comment: uninstall pip and deete pip folders by searching the pip on root then reinstall it again.

Comment: what do u mean by delete pip folders on root? Have used 'sudo find . -type d -name "pip" ', but there is no dir as pip